# Download youtube pytube Custom flow address

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

stream.download() How to obtain the specific download address?

I don't want to download it locally, it's on the cloud function, how can I put it in the object store through the cloud function?

My current code

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytube import YouTube
import pytz


yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLiRkW5Qjy4')
stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
print(yt.streams.filter)

# 获取时间
t = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time()), pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
auth = oss2.Auth('*******','********')
bucket = oss2.Bucket(auth, 'https://oss-cn-XXXX.aliyuncs.com', 'XXXX')
input = requests.get(stream.download)
items1 = name
bucket.put_object(t + '/' + items1+'.mp4', input)
```

The resulting error is

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method
```

Comment: how do you define pytz?

Comment: import pytz    A time of introduction, never mind that

Comment: @Blazing did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: It's been settled